# Can we delete the "getContext" property of HTML5 Canvas tag through script?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

There is a [HTML5 conformance test suite](http://philip.html5.org/tests/canvas/suite/tests/type.prototype.html) with a test for prototype for `HTMLCanvasElement`.

This test fails for Safari, Firefox but passes for Opera on Windows 7.

The test has a script which tries to delete the `getContext` property of the `HTMLCanvasElement`, and further trying to read `getContext` should give `undefined`.

```
delete window.HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext;
_assertSame(window.HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext, undefined, "window.HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext", "undefined");
```

This test fails for WebKit (Safari) because the `getContext` property has `DontDelete` attribute and so it does not allow the script to delete this property.

Is there any description in the HTML5 specification which says deletion of `getContext` property by script is valid?

Comment: It seems useless that it's `DontDelete`, because in WebKit it's possible to just do `window.HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = null`.

Comment: Yes, even though we can overwrite or replace the property's (getContext)'s value with NULL, the property "getContext" still exists holding the last assigned value or default value queried from the JS bindings layer. What this test says is, querying window.HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext should return an undefined value (property does not exist) after it has been deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, the configurability ([[DontDelete]] in ES3, [[Configurable]] in ES5) of `getContext` method is described in WebIDL — as any other `CanvasRenderingContext2D` methods.

Take a look at ["Interface Prototype Object"](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#interface-prototype-object) section, which says:

> There must exist an interface prototype object for every interface defined, regardless of whether the interface was declared with the [NoInterfaceObject] extended attribute. The interface prototype object for a particular interface has properties that correspond to the attributes and operations defined on that interface. These properties are described in more detail in sections 4.5.5 and 4.5.6 below.

And in [4.5.6](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#es-operations), you can see:

> For each unique identifier of an operation defined on the interface, there must be a corresponding property on the interface prototype object (if it is a regular operation) or the interface object (if it is a static operation), unless the effective overload set for that identifier and operation and with an argument count of 0 (for the ECMAScript language binding) has no entries.
>
> The characteristics of such a corresponding property are as follows:
>
> The name of the property is the identifier.
>
> The property has attributes { [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: true, **[[Configurable]]: true** }.

Note the "[[Configurable]]: true" bit (emphasis mine).

Comment: Interesting; the specs for ES5 define `[[Configurable]]` as `If false, attempts to delete the property, change the property to be an accessor property, or change its attributes (other than [[Value]]) will fail.` It looks like `[[Condigurable]]` should be false if it should not be deleted.

Comment: Exactly. That's why conformance test that OP mentioned expects value to be `undefined` ([[Configurable]] is `true` and so property can be deleted).

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any description in the HTML5 specification which says deletion of getContext property by script is valid?

No, nothing explicit in the spec about that. No idea why webkit is different than FF/Opera here (It is Chrome too that disallows delete), but the spec itself does not demand DontDelete for anything on the Canvas. Something else in the ECMAScript spec might.

Firefox 7 and 8 alpha do not delete window.HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext though. They just return true, but getContext is still there. In other words, the test you linked to fails in the exact same place and for the same reason.

Webkit of course still allows you to overwrite whatever you want: `window.HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = undefined`

Comment: What exactly is the criteria to decide which properties can be deleted and which cannot be ?? Is there any link explaining the specification which decides which set of properties of HTML elements can be deleted ??